# How to expand a single row of jqgrid into multiple rows whereas each row and column have different database value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

With a button click in a row I need to expand the row whereas it can have different database values under same column label. It needs to show the transhipment of the ship from port to port. 
Kindly help me deal with this problem or suggest me any reference so that I could try using jqgrid.

In this image a single row is split into 3 rows after the button click. it shows different values under a column. I need a likely output

[image]

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at Guriddo jqGrid subgrid module. See [documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/subgrid/) and [demo here](http://guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/) - click on **Hierarchy** button at left in the accordion menu.

Comment: `var childGridURL = parentRowKey+".json";`   In the example childGrid url is declared like this can you please suggest how to deal with in mvc? @Tony